# embed a map on website without iframe

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have to embed a google map onto a webpage but I am not allowed to use iframes - company policy - is there another way? I checked a few things, like the javascript maps but they seem to be using iframes as well https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial, at least if you check in firebug the maps are in an iframe as well. Is there any API or any other way to do it with no iframe?
thanks

Comment: No, Google Map does not get rendered in Iframe. It builds its structure inside main wrapper we pass in Google Map Constructor. Also if the Google Map would have Iframe how you can Apply css properties since You can not apply CSS properties on cross site iframes.

Comment: Well no, if you attempt to embed a map in your webpage, you have to use an iframe. Here is a map of tower bridge, link generated by google map: <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2483.4229316965316!2d-0.07535649999999999!3d51.5054564!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x487603438b65db49%3A0x9e78421a085a6f2d!2sTower+Bridge!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1441886006615" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>. and that's the code that goes on your page

Comment: There are two ways to render map in web page, one using Iframe and another using API. The example you suggested used Iframe to render Google Map whereas you can do Same thing using Google Map Api. Read more here http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51444/google-maps-iframe-vs-api-which-is-faster-if-any

Comment: Cool, thanks. I had a look at your link, the iframe seems to be creating quite a bit of overhead as opposed to the API. The thing is the map I want to use, has absolutely no functionality other than showing a marker, so the iframe, in terms of functionality would be more than enough. Do you think that using the API for displaying a simple map is overkill - bearing in mind that we can't use iframes? The option I have is either using the API or not displaying the map it seems...

Comment: also, just noticed something interesting. Of the APIs available, the API map embed https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/ uses iframes as well. I think I'll go for the javascript one )

Comment: No It will not, since the API works more master than Iframe. Imaging You are using Iframe, it will give a call Google To build a map for you and then it will get build there on Google and then gets rendered to you. Now Using API will bypass this and will generate the Map on ur page itself. I am going to share an example of creating a simple map in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways of having Google Map on Web Page. Iframe and API. In your case you can use Google Map API V3 to render Google Map since you dont want to use Iframe. The another advantage of using Google Map API instead Iframe is, it works more faster that Iframe. Read here https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51444/google-maps-iframe-vs-api-which-is-faster-if-any

You can use below code to have simple map on your we page

```js
var map;
var geocoder;
var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0), zoom: 2,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.713955826286046, -73.992919921875 ),
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

}
//This will render map on load
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100% }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

You can read more about Google Map JavaScript API V3 here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Hope this helps!